# Capybara/Cucumber can't click on a link/button in a twitter bootstrap rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, cucumber, capybara

Ok so I am pretty sure I am doing something stupid here, but here is the generated HTML for a button on my page 
`<a href="/courses/1" class="btn" id="Enroll in Course">Enroll in Course</a>`

The Cucumber Step Definition are as follows:

```
When /^I go to the course homepage$/ do 
  visit("/courses/#{@course.id}")
end 

Then /^I should see the "(.*?)" button$/ do |button|
  has_button?(button)
end

When /^I click on "(.*?)"$/ do |button| 
  click_on(button)
end
```

The second step which is checking if the button exists on the page passes flawlessly but the third step which is clicking on the button, says button or link not found (`click_on` is supposed to handle both buttons and links).

Any idea why that is happening?

I am using twitter bootstrap and here is the snippet from the erb file that generates the html above:
`<%= link_to 'Enroll in Course',course_path, :class => 'btn', :id => 'Enroll in Course' %>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: ok just tried modifying the second step definition to this: Then /^I should see the "(.*?)" button$/ do |button|
  has_button?(button)
  click_on(button)
end
 and it fails on click_on(button) with this message:Then I should see the "Enroll in Course" button    # features/step_definitions/course_steps.rb:10
      no link or button 'Enroll in Course' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      (eval):2:in `click_on'
      ./features/step_definitions/course_steps.rb:12:in `/^I should see the "(.*?)" button$/'
      features/courses.feature:11:in `Then I should see the "Enroll in Course" button'

Comment: ok just tried to use button_to, instead of link_to and the generated HTML changed to: <input class="btn" id="Enroll in Course" type="submit" value="Enroll in Course"> ...but it still fails!

Comment: I don't think 'Enroll in Course' is a valid HTML id. That could be throwing it off. What exactly are you passing to `click_on`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worst case scenario you can find the element by its css selector and force click it.

```
find('#enrollInCourse').click
```